# Scipy installation, its installed why the traceback?

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, scipy, scikit-learn

I am running the following code (this is the beginning snippet):

```
# Import necessary modules and functions
########################################
# time module, for timing it.
from time import time
global starttime
starttime = time()
# psutil for indentifying processor and memory usage
#import psutil
# csv module for loading csv files
import csv
# numpy, a standard module for working with arrays
import numpy as np
# for randomly shuffling arrays
from random import shuffle
# for computing mean squared errors
from sklearn import metrics
# importing modules that contain models we will use
from sklearn import linear_model, ensemble, gaussian_process
from sklearn import neural_network, svm
# importing memory profiler to enable us to determine peak memory usage
from memory_profiler import profile

# Helpful functions
###################

#psutilpercent = psutil.virtual_memory()
#print "\n", " --> Memory Check 1 Percent:", str(psutilpercent.percent) + "%\n"

# This function is for simplifying reading CSV files
def readCSV(path):
    """
    Read a CSV file of floats, with no headder 
    """
    data = []
    mycsv = csv.reader(open(path), delimiter="|")
    for counter, row in enumerate(mycsv):
        if counter != 0:
            data.append(row)
    return np.asarray(data, dtype=np.float32)
```

However I am receiving the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\regression_v6.py", line 38, in <module>
    from sklearn import metrics
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

But my computer shows Scipy as installed, here is a view of Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features:

[image: Image from programmes and features]

Any ideas?

Comment: `PYTHONPATH`? Can you `import scipy` in a Python shell?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install a special version of scipy? as your screenshot shows 'scipy_umfpack'

I can successfully `import sklearn` using the official version downloaded from sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/

Comment: hmmm I might have installed it as part of the Python XY package https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/

Comment: What would you two like me to provide? Tell me what I should have put down as my answer, not what I did put down.